# Add android package to java Module ( android studio)

Tags: java, android

Sorry this is my first time facing this kind of issue, i have no idea about what to do.

I am working on a project that contains two java Modules ( Module1 , Module2)

**build.gardle for main project:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.client.howara"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        
    }
    
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
   
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':Module1')
    implementation project(':Module2')
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testImplementation  'junit:junit:4.13'
    implementation .....
}
```

**build.gardle for Module1:**

```
apply plugin: 'java'
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation project(':Module2')
}
```

**build.gradle for Module2:**

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

When i try to add an android package to Module1, i get the following error:

Example:

```
error: package android.os does not exist
import android.os.Build;
```

Did i need to modify module1 build.gradle? if yes how ?

Thank you for your help and sorry for my ignorance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### EDIT

You have defined `module1` as a `java` library. So importing any `android` artifact will be prohibited to keep it a `java` library.

If you really want to add `android` artifacts in `module1`, then you need to convert `module1` to an `android` library by doing the following:

#### Module1's BuildScript:

```
// Remove this
apply plugin: 'java'

// Instead add this
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

---

I think what you are doing is fine, however you are not able to state your problem efficiently.

What is happening currently in your `Gradle` `BuildScripts` is this:
Your `App` depends on `Module1` and `Module2`, your `Module1` depends on `Module2` and your `Module2` doesn't depends on either `app` or `Module1`.

```
         App
        / \ 
   Module1 \
      \     \
       \     \
        \     \
         Module2
```

Comment: error when running code :
Cause: compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle

Comment: Now that your `Module1` is a android library, you will need to define the `android` block for its initialization. Copy the `android` block from your `app` build script to `module1` build script.

Comment: Manifest file does not exist : .C:\Users\Me\Desktop\android\client\Module1\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Yea you need to add that as well.  What i would suggest is to create a new android module first, which will have all of this boilerplate already setup for you. Then simply import your already existing module1 to this new one.